# Привилегия «Создавать новые метки» и необходимый уровень репутации

Tags: обсуждение, метки, привилегии

В данный момент привилегия [«Создавать новые метки»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) выдаётся на уровне 300 репутации. Та же самая привилегия на других, прошедших аттестацию, сайтах (например, [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/create-tags) или [SO на португальском](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)) также даётся за 300 и только [на англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) необходимый порог — 1500.

В чате [было высказано предположение](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34518461#34518461), что для нас такой порог слишком низок.

Давайте обсудим, стоит ли повышать? Насколько зрелая у нас система меток, чтобы дополнительно ограничивать её рост и стимулировать участников использовать имеющиеся метки?

---

Информация о недавно созданных метках есть в [инструментах модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=last30days) (ссылка доступна с 10к репутации). Сейчас там такой список:

[haxe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haxe)
[дизайн-языка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0)
[passport](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passport)
[failban](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failban)
[breadcrumbs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/breadcrumbs)
[udid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udid)
[jekyll](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jekyll)
[realloc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/realloc)
[cli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cli)
[рефлексия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f)
[flash-память](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c)
[tin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tin)
[электроника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)
[qregexp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qregexp)
[ogg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ogg)
[autoit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoit)
[esxi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esxi)
[ironpython](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ironpython)
[test](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/test)
[criteria](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/criteria)
[datagrip](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datagrip)
[hack-lang](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hack-lang)
[petapoco](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/petapoco)
[identityserver](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identityserver)
[dahdi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dahdi)
[restsharp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restsharp)
[laravel-elixir](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-elixir)
[android-appbarlayout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appbarlayout)
[locationmanager](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locationmanager)
[aspnetcore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspnetcore)

---

Ещё варианты:

- [На Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) – 1000
- На [испанском SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) – 150

Похоже, что настройка уровня для конкретного сайта вполне реальна.

Comment: Хорошо бы отфильтровать список свежих меток от участников с <1K репы.

Comment: @alexolut согласен, хорошо бы. =) Пока сил не хватило на это.

Comment: Вот кабы можно было организовать двухуровневую систему - скажем, при 300 репутации появляется возможность предложить метку, а при 1500 - возможность принять или отклонить создание предложенной метки (ну и, само собой, создать свою метку)...

Comment: @Akina при 10 репутации можно предложить метку, опубликовав предложение на Мете. Вот пример: [Нужно сделать метку микроконтроллеры и метки по их видам](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/208/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc)

Comment: Я имел в виду, что при 300 автор будет иметь возможность создать draft-метку для своего вопроса. И эта метка не будет отображаться до того момента, как пройдёт утверждения пользователем, имеющим 1500. Если пройдёт. Если проверяющий примет решение об утверждении метки - метка будет внесена в список существующих и будет отображаться в вопросе. Ну а нет - значит, нет...

Comment: всегда было интересно - почему вы считаете большое количество меток проблемой? на enSO сейчас 48 тысяч меток - и никто не умирает. Почему мы, с 3.4 тыс меток, но точно таким же онтопиком, должны бороться с созданием новых меток и всячески его запрещать?

Comment: @PashaPash большое количесво меток — не проблема. Проблема в том, что вместо адекватных меток используют какие-то свежепридуманные. Это случается нечасто, но бывает. Можно ли улучшить ситуацию с помощью повышения ограничения? Возможно да, возможно нет. Для того, чтобы это обсуждать нужны подробные данные по созданным меткам.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Не вижу проблемы - на сайте есть механизим для чистки неадекватных меток - метки, которые используются в одном вопросе, умирают сами по себе. Ну и опять же - вопрос не в этом. Вопрос - почему на enSO 48 тыс меток - не проблема, а у нас - новые метки, при всего 3.4 тыс меток - проблема, которую надо активно бороть чистками и запретами? Обосновывая это тем, что кто-то в чате не знал что такое [оод](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_design). Я уверен, что кто-то думает что питон - это змея. Но я же не предлагаю удалять весь зоопарк питонов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin вот остался бы на том вопросе тег оод - было бы хуже? чем именно хуже? Для сайта, для основной массы участников, а не для трех человек, которые просто пытаются построить строгую иерархию потому что они "любители чистоты". Если ничем - то это просто проявление deletionism-а, которое в принципе не приносит пользы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin похоже, стоит задать отдельным вопросом. потому что о "замусоривании" говорят несколько участников, но при этом никто их них не считает неиспользуемый [tag:python-3.2] c 32 вопросами мусором.

Comment: @PashaPash согласен с вами, deletionism может принести больше вреда, чем неуместная/некорректная разметка вопросов. Кстати, [tag:оод] я восстановил.

Comment: @PashaPash может быть, вы здесь напишете аргументированный ответ об этом? Я поддержу.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ок, попробую, но на это уйдет некоторое время :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет никакого повода поднимать порог. Он *умышленно* сделан ниже порога правки без ревью.

Более того, нет никакой реальной проблемы в существовании кучи меток. Наоборот, проблемой является именно то, что *некоторые участники* считают пустоту и отсутствие меток на вопросе с порядком.

На enSO сейчас 48 тысяч меток. И у них нет проблем ни с поиском решений, ни с поиском ответов. У нас — 3.4 тысячи. Онтопик у сайтов практически одинаковый. Очевидно, что "лишние" 45 тысяч меток никак не снижают доступность информации.

---

То, к чему мы все стремимся — это упорядочивание информации.
Упорядочивание должно облегчать доступ информации. Вот только удаление и чистка меток не имеет никакого отношения к упорядочиванию. На самом деле все наоборот — удаление почти любых меток — это шаг к хаосу:

Насколько я знаю, есть три основных пути к вопросам и ответам. Метки должны быть расставлены так, чтобы не поломать ни один из путей - иначе или вопрос останется без ответа, или его не найдут новые посетители.

- Гугл. Участник приходит прямо в вопрос. Частично ломается отсутствием нужной метки. Лишняя метка этому совсем не мешает.
- Подписка на метки / мониторинг конкретной метки. Ломается отсутствием популярной метки. Лишняя метка мешает этому пути, только если она *уже популярна*, и поставлена на [несоответствующий ей вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BF).
- Мониторинг главной. Ломается отсутствием популярной метки. Лишняя метка мешает только если она стоит в игнор листе у пользователя, что очень маловероятно для непопулярных меток.

Достаточно очевидно, что свежесозданные метки на вопросах не влияют на его доступность *вообще никак*.

---

Реальные пути повышения доступности с помощью меток прямо следуют из списка выше:

- Добавление в вопрос отсутствующих *популярных* меток. Например, установка [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) на вопрос с [vb.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) явно привлечет больше отвечающих, если вопрос не специфичен именно для VB.
- Добавление к вопросу более специфических меток. Например, я не мониторю [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), но часто посматриваю на [sql-server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server).
- Создание синонимов для меток: [aspnetcore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspnetcore), упомянутый в вопросе — это явный промах мимо [asp.net-core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core)
- Снятие *явно ошибочных* меток: вопрос [c++-cli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) при постановке [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) обречен на минуса.

Удаления "лишних" меток из вопроса в этом списке нет и быть не может. Тем более в нем не может быть глобального удаления меток, т.к. удаление глобальной метки никак не может повысить доступность вопросов, ни для спрашивающих, ни для отвечающих. Но очень легко может ее понизить.

Именно поэтому порог добавления сделан таким низким. Создать метку — легко.  Удалить метку, не заспамив при этом очередь ревью — тяжело.

---

На SO принято сжигать метки — но только те, которые явно являются чистым мусором. То, что пара участников в чате не знают что такое [оод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b4), не означает, что ООД не существует. Если новая метка окажется популярной — отлично. Если метка окажется просто редким мусором и будет висеть только на одном вопросе, система удалит ее через 6 месяцев.

---

Удалять же из соображений "чистоты" — это обычный [удализм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC).

Единственным возможным обоснованием *удализма* может быть стремление представить метки в виде четкой иерархии. Например, язык - версия - фреймворк. Но иерархическая структура плохо применима к формату SO: в нее, например, не вписываются любые вопросы по веб-разработке с упоминанием бекэнда.

Знания (мы же тут базу знаний строим?) вообще плохо укладываются в жесткую иерархию. И попытки построить иерархию на неподходящем инструменте — метках — заведомо обречены на провал.

То, что у вас есть привелегия правки без ревью, еще не означает что стоит использовать ее для "чистки". В попытках "навести чистоту и порядок" вы просто удаляете метаданные с вопросов, тем самым мешая остальной части сообщества.

Comment: Не согласен с *"Нет никакого повода поднимать порог."* Я намного больше доверяю в адекватности/понимании сайта участникам с 1.5+ репы, чем с едва за 300. Если вы приводите в пример англ. СО, то в чём проблема поднять порог до 1500?

Comment: По поводу *"Создание синонимов для меток - [tag:aspnetcore], упомянутый в вопросе - это явный промах мимо [tag:asp.net-core]"* — это странноватая мысль. Так что для каждой опечатки будем создавать синонимы?

Comment: *"Создать метку - легко. Удалить метку, не заспамив при этом очередь ревью - тяжело."* Так может это повод повысить порог, чтобы не было мусора и не надо было это делать? У меня такое ощущение, что вы ведёте к тому, что чистки — это всегда плохо. Неужели всегда создаваемые метки нужны и полезны?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov по поводу синонимов - для одиночных - под сомнением, но для тех, где уже есть пару вопросов - стоит создать. потому что синонимизация срабатывает в момент подстановки "неправильной" метки, и предотвращает дальнейшие ошибки. А просто удаление метки - нет

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov на enSO гораздо проще набрать порог в 1500, чем на ruSO - в 300. Там больше поток вопросов.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov еще раз - Т.е. вы предлагаете удалять метки. Зачем? Вы называете редкоиспользуемые или странные метки "мусором" и считаете что они создают проблему. Вопрос - какую именно проблему они создают, кроме того что не нравятся **лично вам**?

Comment: Ожидал эту мысль (по поводу легче набрать 1500), но с ней не согласен. Так давайте, может, все остальные метки также пропорционально понизим? Мне не хочется, но это видимо следовало бы сделать, если следовать этой логике. И почему вы так решили, что там легче набрать? У нас тут знатоков, стабильно отвечающих по определённой теме обычно около десятка. Иногда два. Поэтому просто ответил по теме — и всё. А там совсем не тот уровень и кол-во экспертов, знающих, что отвечать. Намного больше вероятность, что ответит кто-то другой с ещё более содержательным ответом и ещё раньше.

Comment: По поводу удаления меток советую обсуждать это в отдельных темах, для них отведенных (для каждой метки или группы — свои персональные). Я просто предлагаю создавать метки для тех, кто *действительно* эксперт по теме. Если очень надо — пусть попросит на мете, но, уверен, что такая необходимость будет возникать нечасто.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ну т.е. вы просто предлагаете выключить механизим меток, сделав его доступным узкому кругу лиц. например, модераторам. Потому что легкая доступность создания меток несет какие-то проблемы. Какие?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov вот кто-то создал [tag:restsharp]. метка ниочем. я бы (как эксперт в C#) ее не создавал. мусор-мусором. хочу понять, какие именно проблемы создает ее существование на сайте. кто страдает от того, что она есть?

Comment: Никакой не узкий круг лиц, просто у всех у кого репутация выше 1000 или 1500. Проблемы: ненужные метки. А если лёгкая доступность создания меток — это хорошо, может тогда вообще уберём порог создания меток? Пусть их с единицы можно создавать.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ненужные метки - это не проблема сама по себе. это просто состояние системы - есть метки, которые *лично вы* считаете ненужными. а кто-то посчитал нужными. опишите проблему, которую вы пытаетесь решить.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov c 1 нельзя - будут спамить и часто мазать. порог введен для того, чтобы пользователи успели понять что такое метки и как их искать. а не для того, чтобы "запретить"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51661/discussion-between-pashapash-and-vadim-ovchinnikov).

Comment: Вы забыли про ограничение на число меток в вопросе. Некоторые метки, *такие как "программирование"*, стоит удалять просто для того чтобы они не отнимали место у более специфичных меток.

Comment: И да, я пару раз сталкивался с этим ограничением.

Answer (score 5):

Я как любитель чистоты меток и уже участник многих баталий (относительно времени моего пребывания здесь) за удаление вредных (на мой взгляд) приветствую любое повышение репутационного порога создания новых меток. Чем выше, тем лучше. Метки создаются намного чаще, чем стоит.

Comment: Я бы сразу поставил не меньше 1000, у меня впечатление, что как раз где-то на этом уровне репутации у пользователя наконец-то вырабатываются правильные навыки работы с сайтом, общее понимание, что желательно не делать и как не мешать остальной части сообщества.

Comment: Ну хотя бы 1000

Comment: Помню, как-то нас учитель информатики попросил сказать двумя словами "больше или равно". )) Перечитайте мой первый комментарий ещё раз ))

Comment: Хотя у меня совсем не много репутации, и повышение порога лишит меня этой привилегии, я всё же поддерживаю @VadimOvchinnikov. Сейчас достаточно меток, чтобы охарактеризовать любой вопрос, и реальная необходимость в создании новых возникает очень редко.

Comment: Тысяча репутации раз... Что, неужто никто не хочет другую цифру обьявить? )) Тысяча репутации два...

Comment: @AK Можно 1500, как на enSO.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Тысяча пятьсот репутации раз )))

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, тысяча пятьсот репутации два :)

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит. Новые лишние метки всегда можно убрать. Зачем ещё ограничивать?

Comment: Потому что это "можно убрать" -- это лишняя работа, которую нужно кому-то делать. Лучше сразу предотвратить возможность "замусоривания" базы, чем потом разгребать.

Comment: @AK а зачем убирать?

Comment: @AK, кстати да, единичные метки сами удаляются.

Answer (score -1):

Однозначно стоит. Может 1000 - это довольно много, но вот 500 - вполне реальное значение.

Comment: А почему 500? Т.е. вопрос-то шире. Почему набор возможностей вообще зависит от репутации. Казалось бы, если человек прилично ответил на несколько вопросов, т.е. набрал, скажем 50 очков и таким образом подтвердил, что он что-то знает, так пусть и обладает уже всеми возможностями.

Comment: @avp, 50 - мало. 100 очков можно получить вообще ничего не зная по теме сайта, за ассоциацию с другим сайтом stackexchange не связанным с программированием.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, тогда 150. На самом деле важно, только чтобы новому участнику не пришлось долго доказывать, что он полноценен.

Comment: @avp, на самом деле это недонозначный вопрос. Лично для меня постепенное открытие новой функциональности сайта с ростом репутации - это киллерфича репутационной системы so, которая делает ее чуть-чуть больше чем просто плюсомеркой.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, мне кажется, что часть людей такая система просто отталкивает. Допустим, возможность править чужие вопросы,  это может и не важно, а вот дискриминация в полноценном добавлении контента  неприятна.

Comment: @avp Вы так говорите, как будто у Вас репы недостаточно. Хотя, как я вижу, Вы никогда не испытывали подобных "лишений", а репа появилась еще до рождения ruSO.

Comment: @alexolut, я же не о себе говорю, а о новых участниках. Примеряя к себе сложившиеся правила, думаю, что вряд ли, зайдя сейчас на этот сайт, стал бы тут активно действовать

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю, можно так и оставить, разве что можно сделать какую-=то систему фильтрации - какие-то метки запретить, а если "автобан" метка прошла, то её чекает модератор. (реализация хромает, но в принципе, чисто теоретически - это возможно)

Ах, ну и да.

Видел выше что много высказывается в стиле "У них нет опыта работы с сайтом". Какого опыта? Ау. Если у человека как минимум 300 репы, то это значит что в программировании он что-то да шарит. Какие тогда могут быть проблемы с сайтом?

Comment: Шаринг в программировании никак не коррелирует со знанием особенностей сайта.

Comment: Если человек разбирается в программировании, то у него вряд ли появятся проблемы с освоением интерфейса сайта. Это же логично, разве нет?

Comment: брр. как это может быть логично? Я не понял логики)) Типа тыжпрограммист?

Comment: Отнюдь. Вы посмотрите хотя бы на вопросе на Мете, и на репутацию тех, кто их задаёт. Это должно показать Вам, что даже старожилы сайта (заядлые программисты) не знают многих деталей.

Comment: Вы задаёте отдельный вопрос, который требует широкого ответа. Попробую ответить ещё раз: кратко, комментарием. Сайт ru-so -- это достаточно сложная информационная система, а помимо этого -- широкий набор правил сообщества. Правила сбалансированы определённым образом. Для того, чтобы делать какие-то предположения о том, что можно поменять -- крайне желательно понимать, что поменяется в этом месте -- как это аукнется в другом месте. А человек с тремястами репы ещё ни одной очереди на проверку не открывал, он не имеет представления, какие там объёмы и как одни очереди соотносятся друг с другом.

Comment: А кроме того, нужно понимать, что сайт ru-so имеет общий движок со всеми другими сайтами stackexchange, их там около полутора сотен. И вы так дружно любите предлагать широкими жестами "а давайте вот такую фичу введём, а?" -- и не думаете, что продукт owner'ы должны это как-то балансировать и ресурсы программистов не бесконечны! Никто вас не гнобит, что вы -- пользователи второго сорта и салагами не считает, просто проведите некоторое время, осмотритесь -- а когда отведаете вкус устриц -- приходите на мету, вэлком.

Comment: Вы вот попробуйте подумать, что у вас есть три варианта. Один -- программистам ничего на доработку давать не надо, можно просто установить локальную настройку для русского сайта в 1000 единиц репутации. (А программистов занять чем-то другим). И второй -- ваш вариант, когда у вас через год на 150 сайтах будет столько уникальных фич, что никто и не знает где и каких. И третий -- когда нужно фичу протащит сразу на 150 сайтах. Вот что вы сделаете, как глава stackoverflow? Ну-ка?

Comment: На мете нужны soft skills, тут не только важно уметь хорошо писать код!

Comment: "Если у человека как минимум 300 репы, то это значит что в программировании он что-то да шарит", - очень сильное утверждение, я знаю несколько контрпримеров =)

Comment: Создавать новые метки — это не использование интерфейса сайта. Это организация информации на сайте. Для этого нужно понять, по какому принципу создаются метки, как размечаются вопросы. Почему если в вопросе есть слова «массив» и «переменная» — это ещё не повод лепить метки [tag:массив] и [tag:переменная].

Comment: + Какое отношение метки имеют к интерфейсу сайта? Неужели вы считаете интерфейс здесь столь сложным, у нас тут половина надписей на японском, или, может система лабиринта? А может вы просто не хотите делится привилегией с новичками?